# Entity Framework Core Migrations Script Generator in Devops pipeline suddenly introduces errors on old SQL migrations - invalid column, etc

Tags: sql, azure, entity-framework, migration, devops

I have a project based on ASPNETZERO, which uses DotNet Core EF code-first migrations. It has an Azure Devops pipeline to build and deploy it to Azure Web Apps and Azure SQL PaaS database. The SQL migrations are created by Entity Framework Core Migrations Script Generator.

After the most recent commit, the "Release" job failed when running the SQL migration scripts. It gave a series of errors indicating that a number of columns were invalid. Those columns no longer exist in the database, my new commit renames those columns, but no subsequent migrations refer to the old columns. No other information was reported to the logs.

As part of my troubleshooting I connected Visual Studio to the Azure SQL PaaS deployed database, and ran UPDATE-DATABASE. It successfully applied all migrations. I committed the branch again, and again the deployment step threw the "Invalid Column" errors when applying migrations.

Answer (score 1):

To get more information I ran the Devops build task on a remote agent on my own PC so that I could grab the .sql file that it outputs. I executed that .sql against the Azure SQL database in SSMS and it threw the Invalid Column errors I saw in the Azure logs. In SSMS I was able to see precisely where the errors were occurring because the error output takes you to the offending code.

What happened was that in some earlier migrations I had done some data transforms using `migrationBuilder.Sql("Raw SQL command string")`, and those raw SQL commands were using the columns which I have now, much later, renamed. This was no problem for the Visual Studio UPDATE-DATABASE processor because the SQL command string is not parsed. It is just handed through to SQL at runtime, and even then, only if that migration is required. But when the Azure SQL Database deployment generates the .sql output script it turns that SQL string into raw SQL like this:

```
IF NOT EXISTS(SELECT * FROM [__EFMigrationsHistory] WHERE [MigrationId] = N'<MigrationName>')
BEGIN
 UPDATE LinkPersonLMSs 
           set EntitlementStartDate = (SELECT EnrolmentStart from People where People.id = PersonId)                
END;
```

... and *that* query is subject to the SQL query analyser validating the column names before executing it even if the conditional check means the inner query won't execute. If the column "EntitlementStartDate" is renamed or removed in a subsequent migration (as it was in my case), the SQL script causes an error when the SQL query analyser parses it to prepare an execution plan.

**The Solution**
I went back through all my migrations and found every place where I had used `migrationBuilder.Sql("Raw SQL command string")`, and instead made it `migrationBuilder.Sql("exec('Raw SQL command string')")`, so that the exec statement would become the raw SQL, and the payload SQL command string would be rendered as a literal string in the resulting SQL deployment script, and therefore not subject to parsing unless it actually gets executed.

> Note: Any SQL literal symobols inside the command string then need to be escaped, so every single quote (') needs to be changed to two single quotes (''). But that's the only change that should be required.

Now my DEVOPS deployment runs without error, as does UPDATE-DATABASE.